# How can I use Math Formula in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a CPM and I am trying to get all the CPM that are not on track. I have the follow code below and I have put the formula in the WHERE clause, but it shows all results. Instead of only results that are less than 0.9.

```
SELECT cpms.*, site_images.*

FROM ( cpm_images

INNER JOIN site_images ON ( cpm_images.site_image_id = site_images.site_image_id ) )

INNER JOIN cpms
  ON
    ( cpms.cpm_id = cpm_images.cpm_id )
WHERE (  
    ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $data - cpms.cpm_date_start ) ) /
    ( cpms.cpm_views_total * (cpms.cpm_date_end - $data ) )
      ) < 0.9
```

No matter what number is calculated it show the all the results. If the number is below 0.9 it shows, if it is above 0.9, it shows.

UPDATE:
the following data is what is being pulled from the datbase.

```
This is the data from the table.

[cpm_id] => 1
[cpm_title] => Ad Special
[cpm_date_start] => 1556746806
[cpm_date_end] => 1559425206
[cpm_views_total] => 1000
[cpm_views_count] => 500
[cpm_image] => 
[cpm_active] => 1
[site_image_id] => 137
[site_image_file] => cars/3.jpg
[site_image_file_tn] => cars/3.jpg
[site_image_file_org] => cars/3.jpg
[site_image_title] => 
[site_image_description] => 
[site_image_upload_date] => 0
```

When i places numbers in place of the table row names
    ( 500 * ( 1557665447 - 1559425206 ) )
    /
    ( 1000 * ( 1556746806 - 1557665447 ) )

it works, so is it possible that the table row names are not showing as int. yet the table is as follows

```
`cpm_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`cpm_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cpm_date_start` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cpm_date_end` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cpm_views_total` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cpm_views_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cpm_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`cpm_active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL
```

if I have the numbers

```
( 0 * ( 1557665447 - 1559425206 ) )  /  ( 1000 * ( 1556746806 - 1557665447 ) )
```

it equals to 0 so it shows as it is below 0.9
BUT if i have the follow

```
( 1000 * ( 1557665447 - 1559425206 ) )  /  ( 1000 * ( 1556746806 - 1557665447 ) )
```

which equals to 1.91561121265 which it shows in the results, but it shouldn't as it is not smaller then 0.9

UPDATE:
if i use the follow

```
WHERE ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( 1557665447 - 1559425206 ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * ( 1556746806 - 1557665447 ) ) ) < 0.9
```

It works, and the following works too

```
WHERE ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $date - 1559425206 ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * ( 1556746806 - $date ) ) ) < 0.9
```

but as soon as i change it to

```
WHERE ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $date -  cpms.cpm_date_start  ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * ( cpms.cpm_date_end - $date ) ) ) < 0.9
```

it does not work, I even try putting brackets around cpms.cpm_date_end and cpms.cpm_date_start and it still failed.

Comment: What is `$data`? And what data type are `cpms.cpm_date_start` and `cpms.cpm_date_end`?

Comment: $data is a number, it is like 1557665447. It is the UNIX date format. and the cpms.cpm_date_start and cpms.cpm_date_end are INT

Comment: Your code seems reasonable. If you could provide some sample data and expected/actual output it would make it a lot easier to figure out the problem.

Comment: cpm_views_count = 500 - cpm_views_total = 1000 - cpm_date_start = 1556746806 - cpm_date_end = 1559425206

Comment: if i have > 0.9 it shows nothing, no matter if the number is larger or smaller then 0.9, but if i have < 0.9, it shows it no matter what the results.                                                                              ( 500 * ( 1557665447 - 1559425206 ) ) 
 /  ( 1000 * ( 1556746806 - 1557665447 ) ) and this equals too 0.957805606325

Comment: But that's what your `WHERE` clause says: if the number is > 0.9, show nothing and if it's < 0.9 show everything.

Comment: if i change the 500 to 0 in the above example it still shows, and if i change the 500 to 1000, it still shows, even though the number is larger then 0.9 when it is 1000.

Comment: if i use the follow     WHERE ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( 1557665447 - 1559425206 ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * ( 1556746806 - 1557665447 ) ) ) < 0.9  It works, and the following works too   WHERE ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $date - 1559425206 ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * ( 1556746806 - $date ) ) ) < 0.9 but as soon as i change it to       WHERE ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $date -  cpms.cpm_date_start  ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * ( cpms.cpm_date_end - $date ) ) ) < 0.9  it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, I had the cpm_views_start and cpm_views_end wrong way around

```
( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $date - cpms.cpm_date_end  ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * (  cpms.cpm_date_start - $date) ) )
```

How I realized this was when I put it in as follows

```
 SELECT ( ( cpms.cpm_views_count * ( $date - cpms.cpm_date_end  ) )  /  ( cpms.cpm_views_total * (  cpms.cpm_date_start - $date) ) ) AS sum_2
```

it came back a different number. I realize somewhere during coding the string I change the cpm_date_end and cpm_date_start around, yet in where i had it showing on the screen for testing, it was the correct way, so the data on the screen was correct but when it was calculating it in the query, it was wrong way about.

Thank you #nick for doing what you can to help me.